# Pandas slicing quicker way

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apply

I currently have a function and a loop. The aim is to go through every column in the dataframe and if the index value is less than the functino defined value, give a value of 0, if not leave as the current value.

It is working but take ages to run. Can anyone see a better way? I feel I should be using loc or iloc but not sure how to apply

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 20, [5, 3]), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

   A   B   C
0   6  19  14
1  10   7   6
2  18  10  10
3   3   7   2
4   1  11   5

def split(variable_name,sDate,eDate,df):
    if eDate =='end':
        lv=df.index[-1]
        y=np.logical_and(df.index>=sDate, df.index<=lv)
        df['newvar']=y.astype(int)*df[variable_name]
    else:
        lv=eDate
        y=np.logical_and(df.index>=sDate, df.index<=eDate)
        df['newvar']=y.astype(int)*df[variable_name]
    return df

for i in df.columns:
   split(i,1,'end',df)
```

Output

```
   A   B   C
0   0  0  0
1  0   0   0
2  18  10  10
3   3   7   2
4   1  11   5
```

Comment: apologies ... updated with df

Comment: Whats in there in out_cols?

Comment: please update with expected output

Comment: sure updated, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need compare by columns filtered by subset by list and then multiple by [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html):

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 20, [5, 3]), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
print (df)
    A   B   C
0  13   2   2
1   6  17  19
2  10   1   0
3  17  15   9
4   0  14   0

def split(cols,sDate,eDate,df):

    #thanks jpp
    lv = df.index[-1] if eDate == 'end' else eDate

    y=np.logical_and(df.index>=sDate, df.index<=lv).astype(int)
    #alternative
    #y= (df.index>=sDate & df.index<=lv).astype(int)
    df[cols] = df[cols].mul(y, axis=0)
    #numpy alternative for multiple 
    #df[cols] = df[cols].values * y[:, None]
    return df


df1 = split(df.columns,1,'end',df)
print (df1)
    A   B   C
0   0   0   0
1   6  17  19
2  10   1   0
3  17  15   9
4   0  14   0
```

---

```
df1 = split(['A','B'],1,'end',df)
print (df1)
    A   B   C
0   0   0   2
1   6  17  19
2  10   1   0
3  17  15   9
4   0  14   0
```

Comment: Great - that makes sense. So get rid of the loop.

Comment: Does this makes sesne? or is there a better way y=np.logical_and(df.index>=sDate, df.index<=lv).astype(int)

Comment: @fred.schwartz - here is possible use alternative `y= (df.index>=sDate & df.index<=lv).astype(int)`

Answer (score 1):

To get the exact output you mentioned, you can simply write :

```py
df.iloc[:2] = 0
```

This will set any row with an index value < 2 to zero. You can of course specify any range and you won't have to loop, leveraging the fast Pandas vectorized operations.